# How to build a string with map coordinates?

Tags: java, string, foursquare

I use foursquare API and in order to search some places i have to pass as parameter a string with latitude and longitude like this: `37.963790,23.683090`. I also want to add some values to latitude and longitude if i want. After trying with doubles and bigDecimals with no success,  i tried  :

```
Long lat1 = Long.valueOf("37");
Long lat2 = Long.valueOf("963790");
Long long1 = Long.valueOf("23");
Long long2 = Long.valueOf("683090");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(lat1);
sb.append(".");
sb.append(lat2);
sb.append(",");
sb.append(long1);
sb.append(".");
sb.append(long2);
String ll = sb.toString();
```

I have tried all these longs as strings `sb.append(lat1.toString())`.
The string i get in every case seems to be what i want, but the result is not. I don't get an error. If this this parameter is not correctly set you get this error:

```
Error occured: 
[0m[0m13:25:34,463 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   code: 400
[0m[0m13:25:34,463 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   type: param_error
[0m[0m13:25:34,463 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   detail: ll must be of the form
XX.XX,YY.YY (received java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=19 cap=20])
```

This error appeared when i tried to add utf-8:

```
ByteBuffer a =Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(sb.toString());
String ll = a.toString();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens with `37.96,23.68` ?

Comment: It is passed as a string parameter in venuesSearch method of foursquare api. I don't get an error, but the result has nothing inside. The result code is 200 (result.getMeta().getCode() == 200), and it is supposed to have result.getResult().getVenues() but this is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do

```
String iWant = lat1 + "." + lat2 + "," + long1 + "." + long2
```

And if you want to format the numbers differently you use the NumberFormat class

Comment: Or just add String.valueOf().

Comment: Are you passing in the string directly to the api or using a bytebuffer?

Comment: I tried byteBuffer but i got the error i describe above.

Comment: How are you populating the bytebuffer?

Comment: String ll1 = newString(lat1.toString() +"."+lat2.toString()+","+long1.toString()+"."+long2.toString());     
byte[] b = ll1.getBytes("UTF-8");
String ll = new String(b, "UTF-8");

Comment: ByteBuffer a =Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(sb.toString());
String ll = a.toString();

Comment: a.toString() is not going to get you what you want, its going to give you a toString of the bytebuffer itself and not the data in the byte buffer.